# Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver

Tags: android, kotlin

Do I have to use `?.` and `!!.` every time inside `onBindViewHolder` and `onCreateViewHolder` ? Is there any way to avoid this?

`holder.textview.text` and `parent.context` showing this error.

Code :

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder?, position: Int) {
    holder.textview.text = items[position]
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int):ViewHolder {
    return ViewHolder(TextView(parent.context))
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're overriding a method declared in Java, its parameters will have platform types, which means there is no nullability information about them (unless they're [explicitly annotated](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#nullability-annotations)). It's up to you to decide whether or not to mark these parameters nullable. See the official docs about [platform types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types).

In your case, you can safely remove the `?` from both of these parameters, as they'll never be passed `null` values. This relieves you from having to do mandatory null checks.

---

Here's what it looks like with the nullable types removed:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.textview.text = items[position]
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    return ViewHolder(TextView(parent.context))
}
```

Comment: so that means I should use '?' or '!!.' always?

Comment: No, in this case, since you know that `holder` and `parent` will never be `null`, you can make their types `ViewHolder` and `ViewGroup` respectively. With that, you won't be forced to use safe calls.

Comment: And if the method _is_ ever called with `null`, you'll get an exception telling you so.

Answer (score 2):

When you work with nullable types as in your example, you have to apply safety measures to your code. Either you use `?.` every time or you check if your parameter is `!=null`. After such an `if` the compiler knows that calls to this parameter are safe and `null` is not possible.

In your special case it’s not necessary to have nullable types though. Just remove the question marks from the parameters and everything is fine.

Btw: don’t use `!!`, there’s most certainly a better solution

Answer (score 1):

The viewholder will never be null unless if you created null viewholder in your `onCreateViewHolder` when the count > 0, so its safe to remove the `?`

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.textview.text = items[position]
}
```